# Log in / Sign up directly on home page

Tags: django, django-allauth

Instead of logging in on page '../account/login/' i would like to make avaliable for users to log directly on home page for example. What should i do to make it possible? How to connect input fields on home page with allauth? I don't know if this is too complicated to make it work in such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution that works for me. It's not the optimal solution because it's not DRY, so I would be grateful is somebody improves it!

Basically what I did is to render the official allauth login template and copy the HTML code of the form. Then I changed the csrf token and the urls and pasted it to the home page template.

Here is the example code for login/logout. You can do the same with sign up. (Note that I'm using e-mail only and not username to login, your code might be different based on your allauth settings. Take a look at your login and signup templates to see what input fields do you need and its names.)

```
{% load account %}

<h1>Login / Logout</h1>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Loged in with e-mail: {{ request.user.email }}</p>
    <a href="{% url "account_logout" %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <form action="{% url "account_login" %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="login">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <label for="id_remember_menu" class="text-primary">Remember Me:</label>
        <input id="id_remember_menu" name="remember" type="checkbox">
        {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

I would like to improve the code and be able to render the form directly in the home page template with `{{ form }}` instead of copying the HTML. If I manage to do it I will update the reply later.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, please do not forget to update and accept the answer! Thanks

Comment: @ferrangb did you find a way to use {{form}} directly instead of copying the HTML codes?

Comment: @joey, not, I didn't spend more time with it. I know it's not the best way, but it works! :D

Comment: It works. Fantastic. Have you had a chance to figure out how to render it with {{ forms }}

Comment: Guys, if implement `context processor` or `templatetag` it would be possible to use `{{form}}`. Details here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/39235634/4992248

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to, you can put allauth URLs below a different path. allauth uses name based URL reversal, so the new path prefix will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that doesn't help, because i need to have 'login' form and 'signup' form on the same page (home page for example). I need something like this: http://healthifyme.com/ Most websites that use allauth have default URL path (accounts/) but i really have to customize that.

Answer (score 0):

Add login form: On your home page, include a login form with input fields for username/email and password.
or
Submit form to allauth: Connect the login form to the allauth authentication system. Ensure the form's action attribute points to the appropriate allauth login URL (e.g., '/accounts/login/').