# Overriding django allauth to allow signup/signin modal

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to implement basic login (and signup) modal using bootstrap3 and latest django on Python 2.7. I am using Django-allauth library to implement login via facebook and gmail.

By default with django-allauth (e.i its default allauth.account.urls, allauth.account.view, allauth.account.forms files), the user has to navigate to URL http://sitename.com/accounts/login and http://sitename.com/accounts/signup to login and signup respectively.

Could someone please give me a way to override this default behavior such that, the user can login or signup by clicking on the login or signup modal present on homepage (and not by navigating to /accounts/...)?

I am trying to reverse-engineer the django-allauth library to understand what gets called after clicking signup/login page and how can i override it (or what all things do I need to override)?

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: I already answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796

I hope this helps!