# How can I get the django allauth signup page to show up without being at the /accounts/login url?

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-login

A lot of websites such as pinterest, facebook, and tumblr have their signup page at their home page. Is it possible to get the allauth login page to show on the home page rather than the /accounts/login page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log in / Sign up directly on home page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can! Just route whichever url you want to go to the allauth login view

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from main import views
from allauth.account import views as allauthviews

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', allauthviews.login),
    url(r'^someurl/$', views.home)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own home page and only add the signup/login forms there, you can also take a look at this question: [Log in / Sign up directly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796)

Basically, for a login/logout form using e-mail only and not username to login, the code would be:

```
{% load account %}

<h1>Login / Logout</h1>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Loged in with e-mail: {{ request.user.email }}</p>
    <a href="{% url "account_logout" %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <form action="{% url "account_login" %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="login">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <label for="id_remember_menu" class="text-primary">Remember Me:</label>
        <input id="id_remember_menu" name="remember" type="checkbox">
        {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```