# Django login and signup on homepage

Tags: python, django, forms, registration

I am using Django AllAuth for user registration. I want to display the login form and signin form directly on the homepage, similar to Facebook, LinkedIn etc. I have looked at the following posts:

[How to use a signup form outside of the /accounts/ url pattern with Django-AllAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901991/how-to-use-a-signup-form-outside-of-the-accounts-url-pattern-with-django-allau?rq=1)

[How can I get the django allauth signup page to show up without being at the /accounts/login url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777241/how-can-i-get-the-django-allauth-signup-page-to-show-up-without-being-at-the-ac?rq=1)

The login form works, but when the username or password are incorrect the page redirects to /accounts/login and displays the error message. Django-Registration appears to also use the /accounts/* urls. How can I use one of the Django authorization/registration apps and have the login form and signup form on the homepage?

My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: You said *"...similar to Facebook..."*. Well, if you login with incorrect credentials on Facebook, you get redirected to login page where error message is shown. I think your app is also behaving the same way, no?

Comment: That's a good point. Please ignore the similar to Facebook part. The crux of the question is how to override the allauth views!