# How do I make allauth's authentication available on my homepage URL?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-allauth

So i've installed Django allauth to handle my login authentication. However I don't want a seperate URL for login. I want it to be available on my homepage  via Javascript onclick (login box appears when you click a button/no page refresh). But the current allauth URL is located at '/accounts/login'. So as I said I need it located at '/'. How would I do this?

Here is my **views.py**:

```
def boxes_view(request):

    ...

    search = request.GET.get('search')
    posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')
    if search:
        posts = posts.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search) |
            Q(content__icontains=search)
        )
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'polls.html', context)
```

Can I pass it in as context or? How would it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a user to be able to log in using a modal from your homepage, or what you currently see when going to '/'

If so, you don't change the allauth login url. Instead change your javascript code for your login box to present the  contents given [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html#L36).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796).

Comment: I've copied the contents there to my html/javascript code, so that's working and the fields are showing up. But when I submit the form it just redirects to accounts/login or accounts/signup, where the same form shows up again. When I submit that form it works, but do you know how I can make it work initially on the homepage?

Comment: I believe there is a solution to this presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796

Comment: Managed to fix it by passing in the forms as context in my view: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41474532/6733153