# Allauth login on homepage not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

To allow Django's allauth to work on my homepage, I copied the allauth HTML for the login and signup forms to my own base.html (The login form can be seen [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html#L36)).

So this successfully renders the form and its fields on my homepage. However, when I click submit on the login form, it just redirects me to allauth's /accounts/login URL, which renders the same form. Only after that does submitting the form work. It's the same with the signup form when I submit the signup form on my homepage, it redirects me to /accounts/signup and then the signup works after submitting again. How can I make the login/signup work initially from my homepage?

My urls and views:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.boxes_view, name='news'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def boxes_view(request):
   search = request.GET.get('search')
   posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')
   if search:
      posts = posts.filter(Q(title__icontains=search)|Q(content__icontains=search))
   else:
      posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')

   context = {'posts': posts,}
   return render(request, 'polls.html', context)
```

**base.html**

```
...

{% load i18n %}
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
<div class="loginWrapper">
    <div class="loginNested">
    <div class="loginBox">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

...
```

Comment: show your ` url 'account_login'`

Comment: That's allauth's URL. Here's the doc: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py

Comment: does it bring you to the second login page even if the credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes, regardless if the credentials are correct or incorrect, it redirects to /accounts/login

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it by passing in the forms as context in my view:

```
    from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)


    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }
```

Then replacing `{{ form.as_p }}` for `{{ allauth_login }}` in my template:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
<div class="loginWrapper">
    <div class="loginNested">
    <div class="loginBox">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ allauth_login }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This method only works when the credentials are entered correctly. So when entered correctly the form successfully submits and logs in/signs up. However when credentials are entered incorrectly for login, or when a username is already taken for signup etc, it will submit the form anyway and redirect me to /accounts/login or /accounts/signup. This is different to the normal allauth which shows errors without submitting the form. If anyone could tell me how to show errors that would be great, otherwise I will post a seperate question.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in the same.
I solved by inheritance view class of allauth and form class.
I post it as a reference.

In view:

```
from allauth.account.views import LoginView
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

#Custom login form inhertence from allauth.account.forms.LoginForm
class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    error_messages = {
        "account_inactive": _("Edit message as you want or delete it for basic"),
        "email_password_mismatch": _(
            "Edit message as you want or delete it for basic"
        ),
        "username_password_mismatch": _(
            "Edit message as you want or delete it for basic"
        ),
        "too_many_login_attempts": _(
            "Edit message as you want or delete it for basic"
        ),
    }

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Add your own processing here. This is just a basic example of how to
        
        # You must return the original result.
        return super(CustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = CustomLoginForm
    template_name = "site/index.html"
    success_url = "/profile"
```

In the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from profiles import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='index'),
  ]
```

in template use 'form' as tag E.g for error

```
{% if form.errors %}
{% for field in form %}
{% for error in field.errors %}
{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}

{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```