# Override e-mail title in form django-crispy-forms for django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-crispy-forms

I can not find a way to redefine the title and placeholder for the e-mail field in the form of a django-allauth created using django-crispy-forms.

```
templates\account\login.html

{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Log In</h2>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

this code form example created login page with email and password

```
urls.py project level

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    # Django admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # User management
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

in forms to me i found a way to override the password field label

```
app\forms.py
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, PasswordField

class YourLoginForm(LoginForm):
    password = PasswordField(label="custom_label_for_pass ")
```

I want to know how I can flexibly manage forms that are created in this way.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide more context? Maybe some sample code and generated results with the problem highlighted? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Log in / Sign up directly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796)?

The solution there will work, but is maybe not the right or easiest way. Probably you are past this but hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the login form in django-allauth with something like this:

### in app\forms.py:

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # email field
    self.fields["login"].label = "email"
    self.fields["login"].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            "class": "some class",
            "placeholder": "",
            "type": "text",
            "name": "email",
        }
    )

    # password field
    self.fields["password"].label = "password"
    self.fields["password"].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            "placeholder": "",
            "class": "some class",
            "type": "password",
            "name": "password",
        }
    )
```

### in settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    "login": "users.forms.CustomLoginForm",
}
```

also, you can check the [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html) to see for yourself.